# Find last occurrence of a character in SharePoint Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint

Need help in Finding the last occurrence of a character. Below is my requirement.

```
1. DSN_KANSAS_727   - 727
2. DSN_INNOVATION_335  - 335
3. DSN_KANSAS_727B - 727B
4. PCBA_COLUMBIA_16C - 16C
```

I have to extract this output result and this output result should get it and display the power Automatize Email option

Hopefully, this formula field value will not cause a problem in Power Automate. kindly advice.
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below formula to achieve this:

```
=RIGHT([Title],LEN([Title])-FIND("_",[Title],FIND("_",[Title])+1))
```

[image]